# How to get a byte array data into DoubleBuffer

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to extract a set of coordinates from a byte array into a DoubleBuffer.

Below is an example of how I extract a set of coordinates from the main byte array into another byte array.

```
byte intPoints[] = new byte[4];
byte geomCoords[];
...
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stmt.column_bytes(0)); //reads the polygon from db
...
is.read(intPoints); //intPoints now holds the number of points in the polygon
//After this is read the actual coordinate list is next

//Set the size of geomCoords to hold all coordinates,
//There are 2 coordinates per point and each coordinate is a double value(8 bytes)
geomCoords = new byte[ByteBuffer.wrap(intPoints).order(endian).getInt() * 2 * 8];

is.read(geomCoords); //geomCoords now holds all the coordinates for the polygon
```

My questions are:
How can I get geomCoords byte array into a DoubleBuffer?
Or
Can I get this data into a DoubleBuffer without the creation of geomCoords? Speed and efficiency is key, so any shortcut or optimization is most welcome!

Comment: `new ByteBuffer(bytes).asDoubleBuffer()`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So is that?: DoubleBuffer dbuf = new ByteBuffer(geomCoords).asDoubleBuffer();

Comment: How are the coordinates encoded in a byte array?

Comment: Sorry @Joni what do you mean by encoded? Do you mean charsets? If so, I cannot remember, is it important?

Comment: A byte holds numbers from -128 to 127, or from 00 to FF if you prefer hex. How do you encode coordinates in bytes? Also, are these geographic coordinates (like GPS) or screen pixel coordinates?

Comment: @Joni They are in number format.

Comment: They are geographic coordinates but I'll be drawing them using OpenGL 2

Comment: OK, so they are floating point numbers. Are they stored in the usual IEEE754 format or something else? Did the above code, using asDoubleBuffer, not work?

Comment: @Joni Just read up on the database UTF8 encoding apparently, yes 8 Byte doubles, I only say this as I think floats are only 4 byte. Sorry did you say that your putting the kettle on?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement the above with my code, first time playing with byte arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the 8 bytes in the bytes buffer are indeed Doubles, then simply

```
DoubleBuffer dbls = new ByteBuffer(geomCoords).asDoubleBuffer();
```

Now each point can be extracted with `dbls.get();`

Comment: this came up with. Cannot instantiate the type ByteBuffer.
Why is that?

Did a search and found this line: 
dbls=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(geomCoords.length).order(endian).asDoubleBuffer();

Comment: @Ayman You can't create a `ByteBuffer` with a constructor. You have to use one of the `static` factory methods.

Comment: Oops. Yes you need to wrap the byte array or use another static factory.

Comment: @Ayman DoubleBuffer dbls = new ByteBuffer(geomCoords).asDoubleBuffer(); worked! But I have found that I need it to be direct not indirect. How can I do this?